Schatten p-norm inequality $\|A-B\|_p ≥ \|D_A-D_B\|_p$
I am seeking a reference or proof for the following.
Given two Hermitian matrices $A$ and $B$, and their corresponding diagonal matrices $D_A$ and $D_B$ containing their eigenvalues, I am interested in the inequality:
$ \|A - B\|_p \geq \|D_A - D_B\|_p $
where $\| \cdot \|_p$ denotes the Schatten $p$-norm. Here, $\|X\|_p = \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i(X)^p \right)^{1/p}$ for a matrix $X$, where $\sigma_i(X)$ are the singular values of $X$.
Could someone please provide a reference, proof, or relevant insights regarding the validity of this inequality? Any assistance or pointers to relevant sources would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

What do you mean by "corresponding diagonal matrices"? Are these the matrices of eigenvalues?

Yes, I'm sorry!

You would probably also need the condition that the diagonal entries of $D_A$ and $D_B$ are ordered; otherwise, $A = B = \text{diag}(1,0)$ but $D_A = \text{diag}(0,1)$, $D_B = \text{diag}(1,0)$ would be a counter-example.
But in that case, I don't think the statement is true without further assumptions...
Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\1&0\end{pmatrix}$, $B = \text{diag}(-1,0)$, and $p=\infty$. Then the left-hand side is about 1.618, yet the right-hand side is equal to 2, since the eigenvalues of $A$ are 1 and -1, and those of $B$ are -1 and 0...
